# Extracting values between two delimiters for an entire column in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, substring, postgresql-9.6

I am looking for a way to extract all substrings between two delimiters over an entire column.I have found ways to do this for each string separately, but I need something I can apply over the entire column.

For example if I have a column called "NAMES" that contains the below values:

- 1235_brandon_098410090
- 1242353_sam_1920420101222
- 134214_kristein_39402384

I want my output to be

- brandon
- sam
- kristein

how do I do this?

I've tried this:
regex_substr(names,'_(.*?)_'

Query Error: error: function regex_substr(character varying, unknown) does not exist

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, I think you can use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(names, '_', 2), '_', -1)
```

This extracts the second value delimited by underscores, which is what all the sample data suggests is needed.

EDIT:

Your error message looks like Postgres.  This is the equivalent in Postgres:

```
select v.*, split_part(names, '_', 2)
from (values ('1242353_sam_1920420101222')) v(names);
```

In Postgres, you can use `substring()` with a pattern as well:

```
select v.*, substring(names from '[A-Za-z]+')
```

Comment: Query Error: error: function substring_index(character varying, unknown, integer) does not exist i keep getting this error. I am using postgresql v 9.6

Comment: @jayzers27 . . . `substring_index()` is and has been a part of MySQL basically forever (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).  That error does not look like a MySQL error.

Comment: I works just fine. Can you post your query please in the thread.